# Is the vulnerability reporting to our website actually a scam?

Tags: vulnerability, scam, bug-bounty

An individual contacted us claiming that he discovered vulnerabilities in our website. He also showed his intention to show us detailed information about the vulnerabilities, including how to reproduce them. He even asked our permission before reporting the vulnerabilities.

Should I ignore this email or reply to it? I don't have experience in this matter, so I would like to receive some feedback or your personal experience.

Comment: How on earth could we determine if it is a scam? How can we then advise on whether to ignore it or not? What's the harm in engaging? What's your fear? If you want feedback, we can't give it to you, you will have to see what the person says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a scammer, or it could be a genuine white-hat who is trying to help you. Or it could be someone who has found a real vulnerability, and is hoping to blackmail you into paying them.

If they're being polite and asking for permission before reporting that's a good sign (rather than demanding money up front) - but certainly no guarantee.

Often the best approach is to reply to their email, ask whether they can provide further details (ideally providing them a PGP key or some other secure way to do so), and to *make it clear that you don't have a bug bounty program, and can't offer rewards for reported vulnerabilities*.

If they're willing to provide the info, then great. And if you can credit them somewhere (or give them some freebies/swag/service credits/etc) then even better.

If they refuse or demand money, then it's almost certainly a scam, and you can block them and move on.

---

Also if you don't have a vulnerability disclosure policy then it might be a good idea to make one. The [Vulnerability Disclosure OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Vulnerability_Disclosure_Cheat_Sheet.html) has some useful guidance.